# How to simply add more years into DatePicker in GWT and use the format to DD-MM-YYYY when a date was selected?

Tags: gwt

Look at this code,

```
DateBox myDateBox=new DateBox();
myDateBox.getDatePicker().setYearAndMonthDropdownVisible(true);
DateTimeFormat dateFormat = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("DD-MM-YYYY");
myDateBox.setFormat(new DateBox.DefaultFormat(dateFormat));
```

Ok, when I clicked on the DateBox the DatePicker got popped up but I could not see years like from 1600, so How to add more years into DatePicker?

Alos, I want to use the format to DD-MM-YYYY when a date was selected but when clicked on a date nothing appeared in the DateBox?

Answer (score 0):

For years like 1600, I cannot help you. But for the format, perhaps the problem is capitalization. I think you should use the format

```
DateTimeFormat dateFormat = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
```